# sesamanuel document class problem

Tags: header-footer

i begin to use the `sesamanuel` document class.

i begin with this code :

```
\documentclass{sesamanuel}
\begin{document}
\themaG
\chapter{ma vie}
bla bla bla bla
\themaF
\chapter{ma vie}
\themaG
\chapter{ma vie}

\end{document}
```

but i have finally this

[image]

how to have my pdf without those things

and sorry for my english its my third language

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what the issue, or question, is. The text snippet you've circled in red is outside the crop marks and hence won't show up in the final product.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the `sesamanuel` documentation (chapter 4 "Option de compilation", page 6)

> `crop` ou `nocrop` pour obtenir, ou non, les repères photographiques
>   de coupe. L’option par défaut est `crop`.

The above loosely translates to:

> `crop` or `nocrop` to include or exclude respectively, crop marks.
>   The default option is `crop`.

So, adding the `nocrop` option as follows `\documentclass[nocrop]{sesamanuel}` will remove the crop marks as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope you need to remove the `slug line` which comes with `crop.sty`, please try with the below modified tags:

```
\documentclass{sesamanuel}

\makeatletter
\let\CROP@@info\relax
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\themaG
\chapter{ma vie}
bla bla bla bla
\themaF
\chapter{ma vie}
\themaG
\chapter{ma vie}

\end{document}
```

This suggestion helps to remove the `slug line` only, if you want to remove both the `crop mark` and `slug line`, then please follow `leandriis` suggestion...